# task scheduler thinks python script is still running

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, windows-shell

I have a python script which in turn executes other python scripts.
I put this as a task on WinXP task scheduler. the thing runs - command prompt is opened, sparks are flying, magic happens... eventually the task is completed, I get a nice 
'print script ended!!'
and back to prompt. but Task Scheduler thinks the task is still running ! which in turn prevents it from running it again on daily basis.

so I tried making a BAT file which just calls the script:

```
script.py
echo pyfinished
```

to my surprise cannot see 'pyfinished' at the end ...

Comment: What does `script.py` look like?

Comment: are you using threads in your script ?

Comment: With no code, there's really not much we can do except speculate randomly.  Please create the **smallest** piece of Python code that reproduces the problem and post that **small** piece of code as part of your question.

Comment: I take it you mean you ran the batch file manually? Between that and Task Scheduler's behavior, it sounds like your Python script isn't actually exiting. Check in Task Manager.

Comment: @all the script is one of my company's nightly build scripts too huge to produce any piece of example code. So guessing is what I am actually looking for. The scripts call to many test scripts which use threads - so guessing the process didn't quit seems like a very reasonable one.

Comment: My current workaround is to let Task Scheduler kill the process after 23 hours.

Comment: @all the reason was os.system('cmd /K script.py') - the /K cause the process to never exit.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem as well.  What I did to make sure the script stops is configure the task to stop after 1 hour (or however long the script(s) should take).  This kills the task and thus when the task schedule comes around again, it has no problem kicking off.

As for why Task Scheduler can't detect the script is finished, I have no idea.  It's royally annoying.

Answer (score 0):

a line with `os.system('cmd /K script.py')` makes the process stay alive until I manually kill it.

Comment: Yes, the parent process will block waiting for the child process to exit. But why are you running double-scripts, anyway?

Comment: I'm maintaining it and it ain't (severely) broken